# how to configure h2 on test and MYSQL for prod automatically

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

How to configure h2 only for tests and MySQL for prod in Spring Boot  ?

I tried to use spring.profiles.active but I expect difference results ,

If I run integration test I need automatically use H2 for tests and I if run application I need run with MYSQL = prod

Comment: Don't. Use something like testcontainers to bootstrap the actual db instead. This will prevent you from issues with different databases (and no running H2 with compatibility mode for MySQL is not running MySQL nor does it behave the same!).

Comment: Ok , thanks I will try to implement it .

Comment: Assuming you are using a recent version of Spring Boot (3.1) that should be as easy as including some dependencies.